# How to center divs within a div horizontally with fixed width and margins?

Tags: html, css, centering

Is it possible to Center Horizontally several divs inside a div with fixed width height and margins?

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<html>

   <div id="maincontainer">

         <div id="microcontainers"></div>

         <div id="microcontainers"></div>

         <div id="microcontainers"></div>

         <div id="microcontainers"></div>
   </div>

</html>
```

**And the CSS:**

```
#maincontainer{
width:1120px;
height:auto;
background-color:#E4E4E4;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 124px;
padding: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
overflow: hidden;    
}

#microcontainers{
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    border:  #999 1px solid;
    margin: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

Thank you and more power!

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Joe i think you are looking like this :- **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/32pbc/3/)**

i have achieved made some changes in your css i have added few points :-

1. I gave `display:block` & `text-align:center` to your parent div **#maincontainer** &

`dispaly:inline-block` to your child div **#microcontainers**

So through this method you can get your desired result and you can remove add extra **div's** that will come in center always...

**CSS**

```
#maincontainer {
    background-color: #E4E4E4;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
}


#microcontainers {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `id` is a unique element, you can not use same id multiple times. Instead of using `id`, use `class`. For aligning center of your div, you can create one main div which is holding all other divs, like:

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="microcontainers"</div>
  <div class="microcontainers"</div>
  <div class="microcontainers"</div>
</div>
```

Define a width to the `#main` and use `margin:0 auto;`

```
#main {
  width:1000px;
  height:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.microcontainers {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  border:  #999 1px solid;
  margin: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

Using this method you can centered all your elements inside `#main`.

Comment: Thanks Atal. This is a new knowledge for me. Thanks. Now I know.

Answer (score 0):

Use this ..

```
    #microcontainers{
        width: 400px;
        height: 600px;
        border:  #999 1px solid;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: This is good. But I cannot put margin:auto; to my #microcontainers because I have to keep a distance among them. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center horizontally and display horizontally you could use the next markup:

**HTML**

```
<div class="Macrocontainer">
        <div class="microcontainers">
        </div>
        <div class="microcontainers">
        </div>
        <div class="microcontainers">
        </div>
        <div class="microcontainers">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
   .microcontainers {
        width: 400px;
        height: 600px;
        border: #999 1px solid;
        margin: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
        padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        display: block;
    }

    .Macrocontainer {
        overflow:auto;
        width:3000px; /*set the width desired to accomodate the quantity of divs needed*/
    }
```

if you want to center each div horizontally but display vertically you could use the next markup

**HTML**

```
<div class="Macrocontainer">
        <div class="Container">
            <div class="CenterDiv">
                <div class="microcontainers">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Container">
            <div class="CenterDiv">
                <div class="microcontainers">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Container">
            <div class="CenterDiv">
                <div class="microcontainers">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Container">
            <div class="CenterDiv">
                <div class="microcontainers">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .microcontainers {
        width: 400px;
        height: 600px;
        border: #999 1px solid;
        margin: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
        padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }

    .Macrocontainer {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .Container {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .CenterDiv {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 400px;
    }
```